# Calling two functions on same click event with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, onclick, tooltip

Does anybody know if it is possible to call two separate functions on the same event with d3.js? I know you can do this in JavaScript by just separating the two with a semicolon but have not been successful doing this with my particular case. I am using a force-layout graph with tool-tips and have two separate tool-tips that I want to use. On mouseover, a tool-tip appears saying the name of the node and then on click, I want a second tool-tip to show its description. On that click though, I would like for the first tool tip to go away. Here is the block of code that I am using:

```
         .on("click", describe_tip.show)
         .on("mouseover", tip.show)
         .on("mouseout", tip.hide)
```

I want to call `tip.hide` along with `describe_tip.show` but do not know the correct syntax.

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can wrap the two function calls you want to make in an anonymous function, e.g.

```
.on("click", function(d){
    describe_tip.show(d);
    tip.hide(d);
})
```

Note that since `describe_tip.show` and `tip.hide` both require data `d` as an argument, you need to pass that to them. Recall that when passing an anonymous callback function to `.on("click", callback)`, D3 passes:

> > the current datum d and the current index i, with the this context as the current DOM element

to the `callback` function ([docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#on)).

Comment: Awesome that works! Thank you. I failed to include the `(d)` for `describe_tip.show` and `tip.hide`